# What's the performance impact of consuming Kubernetes ConfigMaps mounted as files?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

So I know this is possible and using ConfigMaps this way comes with auto update capability, which is great.

But when consuming such ConfigMap in a pod, what's exactly happening? Do we read these as actual files from disk? Or are these files stored in some sort of in-memory fs / ETCD?

My code would read these "files" on each req, but if this means actual disk operations, that's not good. So how does this work and how fast this is?

Comment: How many times are you reading the ConfigMap data?  (Just once at startup?)  My intuition is that the performance cost of this would be negligible especially once the application is running, but as with any performance question, the only real answer will come from benchmarking your actual application.

Comment: We would read those configs on every request. Otherwise we couldn't use updates kubernetes provides via autoupdate, since we would only get the initial config.

Comment: Can you check the below link which might be useful to you.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically

Comment: Thx. Checked it. But this article doesn't talk about performance or how mounted configMaps are implemented internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when consuming such ConfigMap in a pod, what's exactly happening?
> Do we read these as actual files from disk? Or are these files stored
> in some sort of in-memory fs / ETCD?

ConfigMaps are stored in ETCD data-store

> My code would read these "files" on each req, but if this means actual disk operations, that's not good. So how does this work and how
> fast this is?

Depends on how are you consuming the `ConfigMap`s. You can either inject a specific key/value pair as environment variable in your `Pods` and mount them as volumes.

In case of mounting, `ConfigMap`s are placed as files in Pods' ephemeral storage. They are placed only once, at the start of Pod's life-cycle.
Application running inside the Pod would be reading the data directly from the file inside against every request.

IMO, performance penalties in terms of reading won't that big since ETCD pods/daemon services reside in the same k8s cluster along with rest of the services. However, if your ETCD is part of some other external node, you may face network level latency.

Check out this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/) for further reading